# How to properly use gofstat in R?

Tags: r, goodness-of-fit

I'm trying to write a bit of code in R that takes sample data from Excel and identifies the most fitting distribution to the data, and then the parameters for said distribution. After a bit of Googling, I decided to try fitdistrplus for fitting the distributions, and saw that gofstat is a function that can be used to check the goodness-of-fit. I wanted to compare the GOF statistics to find the most fitting distribution in a loop.

The initial part of my code is literally just importing my sample data from Excel (I created a 1000 values, normally distributed, in Excel, and saved it as a single column in CSV format), and trying to fit it to a distribution and plot the results.

```
library(fitdistrplus)
testData = read.table("C:\\Users\\Havok\\Documents\\Skripsie\\Excel\\NormalTest1.csv", header=FALSE)
(func <- apply(testData, 2,  fitdist, "norm"))
gofstat(func)
for(i in 1:1000)
  plot(f[[i]])
```

However, whenever I try to run the code, I get the error messages

> > gofstat(func)
> >     Error in gofstat(func) : 
> >       argument f must a 'fitdist' object or a list of 'fitdist' objects.
> >     for(i in 1:1000)
> >     +   plot(f[[i]]) 
> >     Error in f[[i]] : subscript out of bounds

The plots still appear despite the "subscript out of bounds" error (I think it might be due to stray negative values in the imported data), but I really want to find out what is wrong with my gofstat usage. Any ideas?

P.S. My R experience is limited to a single module we had in university, and it was pretty basic. So any advanced tricks would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need to use apply, that makes it a rolling function.

```
library(fitdistrplus)
set.seed(1234)
testData = rnorm(1000)
fit <- fitdist(testData, "norm")

plot(fit)
gofstat(fit)
```

Answer (score 3):

Martin, here are some general tips plus sample code to help you.

1. Its handy to just use `rnorm()` to generate a list of random numbers in R. I am using set.seed to pin the same series of random numbers during testing.

   ```
   testData <- rnorm(1000)
   head(testData) 3 see first few elements
   [1] -0.6264538  0.1836433 -0.8356286  1.5952808  0.3295078 -0.8204684
   ```
2. Have you looked at the documentation for this package? use *? for help*

   ```
   ?fitdistrplus
   ?gofstat
   ```
3. You want to **plot over the distribution types** not the data.

So:

```
library(fitdistrplus)
# setting where random number sequence starts so you can reproduce results. 
set.seed(1)
testData <- rnorm(1000)
# list of distributions
#   see help  for full list e.g. "norm", "lnorm", "exp" and "pois",
#   "cauchy", "gamma", "logis", "nbinom" (parametrized by mu and size),
#   "geom", "beta", "unif", and "weibull"
dist <- c("norm", "unif")

# Loop through your list of distributions
for(i in length(dist)){
  x <- fitdist(testData, dist[i])
  gofstat(x)
  plot(x)
}
```

Add to list of distributions in dist. Note some distributions expect all values to be positive (e.g. Poisson - as it is about counts).

Are you using RStudio? Your back arrow in Plots tab will let you go back and forth between your plots.

M

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I did indeed look over the documentation for the package, but could not figure out my problem from there, so these answers really help. And f was supposed to be func - merely a typo on my end. Sorry about that.

Comment: I have added some code to loop through distributions as I think that is what you are trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: You've just saved me SO much time. Thanks so much for this!